# Example for customizing the ignored pattern list in Django's collectstatic

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

Like other questions here, I want to ignore my `.scss` files when running collectstatic. But because I'm using Heroku, which runs a collectstatic automatically, I would rather customize `collectstatic`'s ignore pattern list rather than change the management command.

Django 2.2 provides [a way to do this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#customizing-the-ignored-pattern-list), as documented below:

> The default ignored pattern list, ['CVS', '.*', '*~'], can be
>   customized in a more persistent way than providing the --ignore
>   command option at each collectstatic invocation. Provide a custom
>   AppConfig class, override the ignore_patterns attribute of this class
>   and replace 'django.contrib.staticfiles' with that class path in your
>   INSTALLED_APPS setting:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.apps import StaticFilesConfig

class MyStaticFilesConfig(StaticFilesConfig):
    ignore_patterns = [...]  # your custom ignore list
```

My problem is that, this being my first Django project, I don't quite know how to provide a custom AppConfig class (and diving into the AppConfig docs hasn't helped). I mean, should I add this class to a whole new app or use an existing one? Is this class going to be in a `apps.py` file? If so, what should be the best app to do so? So I'm asking if anyone could provide me with an example of the best practice.

For reference, right now my app structure is like this (with all templates, assets and apps grouped together in their own folders rather than within each app):

```
-- project_name
  -- assets
    -- app1
  -- templates
  -- project_name
    -- app1
    -- app2
    -- __init__.py
    -- settings.py
    -- urls.py
    -- wsgi.py
```

**UPDATE:**
As [Nico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566899/nico-griffioen) suggested, I've created an app called static in `project_name.project_name` with only an init.py file and an apps.py. The `apps.py` is exactly like the doc example:

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.apps import StaticFilesConfig

class StaticConfig(StaticFilesConfig):
    name = 'static'
    ignore_patterns = ['CVS', '.*', '*~', '*.scss']
```

However, I'm running into errors when replacing `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

- Replacing it for `'project_name.static'` makes the terminal not understand the `collectstatic` management command.
- Adding `'project_name'` *after* `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` (i.e.
  not removing the later) makes it ignore the overwrite and collect the
  `.scss` files.
- Replacing for `'project_name.static.apps.StaticConfig'` throws a
  `Cannot import 'static'.` error

**UPDATE 2:**
After I rollbacked the app creation, I tried is again, but now, instead of using the `startapp` with the file path, I created the app on the project root, tested it, then moved it manually to my apps' folders, and tested it again. For some reason I don't quite understand, this time I replaced `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` for `'project_name.static'` and now it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to some other app, or even create just a file called static in the root of project_name and refer to the class inside this file in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` directly, but the recommended way to provide AppConfigs is inside an apps.py file inside the application package.

If you have no app where this `AppConfig` could be placed, I think the best practice would be to create a package under project_name.project_name called static, with only an **init**.py file and an apps.py file.

In this file you can create your `AppConfig` in the way you described.
Your file structure will then look like this:

```
-- project_name
  -- assets
    -- app1
  -- templates
  -- project_name
    -- app1
    -- app2
    -- static
       -- __init__.py
       -- apps.py
    -- __init__.py
    -- settings.py
    -- urls.py
    -- wsgi.py
```

Comment: I've added it, but it does't quite work yet. There is some kind of issue when replacing  'django.contrib.staticfiles` as stated in the docs. I'll update my question accordingly.